# List the customer and art title that has been sold 2 times

Tags: mysql

[image]Down below is my SQL code
can anyone help me this question?
it's for my assignment, would appreciete it for your help thank you
I'm using MySQL WorkBench

Q: List the customer and art title that has been sold at least 2 times.

Sorry in advance if some of my code is wrong as im still at the basic of learning it

```
-- create a database
CREATE DATABASE ArtCase_db

-- after create databse, create the tables in artcase schema. 
Use ArtCase_db;

CREATE TABLE Customer (
   CustomerID VARCHAR (10),
   custName   VARCHAR (25),
   Gender     VARCHAR (6),
   Address    VARCHAR (150),
   DOB        DATE,
   Mobile     VARCHAR (12),
   Credit     DECIMAL,
   PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID));
   
   CREATE TABLE Artist (
   ArtistID VARCHAR (15),
   ArtistName VARCHAR (25),
   CustomerID VARCHAR (10),
   PRIMARY KEY (ArtistID, CustomerID),
   FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) references Customer(CustomerID));
   
   CREATE TABLE Art (
   ArtTitle VARCHAR (25),
   ArtType  VARCHAR (18),
   ArtistID VARCHAR (15),
   CustomerID VARCHAR (10),
   PRIMARY KEY (ArtTitle, ArtistID, CustomerID),
   FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) references Artist(ArtistID),
   FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) references Customer(CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Purchase_History (
   PurchaseDate   DATE,
   PurchasePrice  DECIMAL,
   ArtTitle       VARCHAR (25),
   ArtistID       VARCHAR (15),
   CustomerID     VARCHAR (10),
   PRIMARY KEY (PurchaseDate, ArtTitle, ArtistID, CustomerID),
   FOREIGN KEY (ArtTitle) references Art(ArtTitle),
   FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) references Artist(ArtistID),
   FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) references Customer(CustomerID));
   
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES ('1', 'Simon Jakson', 'Male', 'Blk 252 Ang Mo Kio Ave 4 Singapore 560252', '1960-07-25', '065-98423838', '10000'),
       ('2', 'MIchael Sadiputra', 'Male', '627A Aljunied Road #06-10/11 Biztech Centre Singapore 389842', '1989-04-28', '065-68462350', '5000'),
       ('3', 'Rajesh laho','Male', '513 Serangoon Road #04-01 218154 Singapore', '1960-09-25', '097-9032522', '22000'),
       ('4', 'Raj hula', 'Male', '460 Alexandra Road #38-00 Psa Building, 119963, Singapore', '1960-07-26', '062747111', '10000'),
       ('5', 'Amitava sakoto', 'Male', '1 Scotts Road #16-12 SHAW CENTRE 228208 Singapore', '1960-07-27', '067320113', '5000'),
       ('6', 'Maria nina', 'Female', '59B Jalan Besar 208810 Singapore', '1960-07-29', '062962196', '4000'),
       ('7', 'Sahibha denny', 'Male', '6 Aljunied Ave 3 #04-00 389932 Singapore', '1961-07-25', '065-67462222', '2000'),
       ('8', 'Kaury misa', 'Female', '14th Floor Dalamal Towers 44552 Singapore', '1962-07-25', '091288354555', '20000'),
       ('9', 'manvender kurau', 'Male', '3028A Ubi Road 3 #01-89 408657 Singapore', '1963-07-25', '067491123', '20000'),
       ('10', 'Rahul jari', 'Male', '487 Bedok South Avenue 2 469316 Singapore', '1964-07-25', '064424306', '20000');
  
INSERT INTO Artist
VALUES ('1', 'James Arthur', '2'),
       ('54', 'Sam Smoth', '5'),
       ('26', 'Florine D', '1'),
       ('1', 'James Arthur', '3'),
       ('21', 'Macallen', '6'),
       ('54', 'Sam Smoth', '4'),
       ('32', 'John Mars', '9'),
       ('54', 'Sam Smoth', '8'),
       ('20', 'Jasmine', '7'),
       ('52', 'Kokanto', '10');
  
INSERT INTO Art
VALUES ('The Tigers Says Sorry', ' Limited Edition', '1', '1'),
       ('The Finders', 'Gold Edition', '54', '5'),
       ('Within Me You Stay', 'Platinum', '26', '2'),
       ('The Tigers Says Sorry', 'Limited Edition', '1', '4'),
       ('Single Malt', 'Platinum', '21', '6'),
       ('The Keepers', 'Gold Edition', '54', '3'),
       ('The Three Mice', 'Planitum', '21', '9'),
       ('Noman White', 'Limited Edition', '52', '8'),
       ('Wielk', 'Platinum', '20', '10'),
       ('Ninety Parallel', 'Limited Edition', '32', '7');

INSERT INTO Purchase_History
VALUES ('2015-01-20', '500', 'The Tigers Says Sorry', '1', '1'),
       ('2017-05-15', '800', 'The Finders', '54', '5'),
       ('2018-07-25', '2000', 'Within Me You Stay', '26', '2'),
       ('2019-08-5', '700', 'The Tigers Says Sorry', '1', '4'),
       ('2019-08-05', '5000', 'Single Malt', '21', '6'),
       ('2020-08-08', '1400', 'The Keepers', '54', '3'),
       ('2018-05-22', '1800', 'The Three Mice', '21', '9'),
       ('2019-08-05', '800', 'Noman White', '52', '8'),
       ('2019-01-20', '600', 'Wielk', '20', '10'),
       ('2015-04-15', '5000', 'Ninety Parallel', '32', '7');
```

Comment: Please tag only 1 RDBMS; what are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Also, I think we need to see your best effort(s) to date - otherwise we're just doing your homework for you, which is bad, and will be immediately downvoted.

Comment: Also, I think art needs an art_id

Comment: i'm using My SQL

Comment: The table that the teacher gave me did not have art_id, only ArtTitle and ArtType

Comment: Well, fair enough, but this is an example of where we would normally use a surrogate PK. In fact, there's lots of scope for normalisation here, but I guess that's beyond the remit of your answer.